# Problem installing Microsemi LiberoSoC on Ubuntu

Tags: installation, java

I asked this question on the [Electronic Engineering StackExchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/96879/installing-microsemi-actel-libero-on-ubuntu/96881?noredirect=1#comment189152_96881) but could not find the right answer and the question was closed as it was flagged unrelated.

> I am trying to install the latest version of the [Libero SW tool](http://www.microsemi.com/products/fpga-soc/design-resources/design-software/libero-soc#overview)s set
>   from Microsemi/Actel on my Ubuntu laptop.
>
> The web site of the company says that their SW only supports the RH
>   linux and they don't mention Ubuntu anywhere on their site. But I only
>   have access to Ubuntu and therefore need to find a way to install it
>   so I can work on my project.
>
> I have followed the [instruction of Microsemi](http://www.microsemi.com/document-portal/doc_download/131602-libero-ide-and-software-installation-and-licensing-guide) and installed all the
>   necessary libraries before running the installation program, but I
>   still can't get this to work.
>
> Does anyone knows if SW for RH can be installed on Ubuntu? Do I need
>   to add extra libraries that are not part of current installation I
>   have?
>
> My installation is "Linux 3.8.0.32-generic x86_64"
>
> Thanks in advance for your help.

First I could not install it at all, but after I installed some fonts as I found from the following line, I got a bit further and got the following error message:

> Preparing to install... Extracting the JRE from the installer
>   archive... Unpacking the JRE... Extracting the installation resources
>   from the installer archive... Configuring the installer for this
>   system's environment... strings: '/lib/libc.so.6': No such file
>
> Launching installer...
>
> Graphical installers are not supported by the VM. The console mode
>   will be used instead...
>
> Invocation of this Java Application has caused an
>   InvocationTargetException. This application will now exit. (LAX)
>   /lib/libc.so.6

After I searched for it I found it under multiple locations on my installation

> sudo find / -name "libc.so.6"
>
> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
>
> /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
>
> /lib32/libc.so.6

and then created a link to fix that:

**sudo ln -s /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /lib/libc.so.6**

Now I am going further in the installation, but it still not evne starting the installation!
This is the last error I am getting:

> Launching installer...
>
> Graphical installers are not supported by the VM. The console mode
>   will be used instead...
>
> Invocation of this Java Application has caused an
>   InvocationTargetException. This application will now exit. (LAX)
>
> Stack Trace: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   /tmp/install.dir.10759/Linux/resource/jre/lib/i386/xawt/libmawt.so:
>   libXtst.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory

I am not an expert on Linux, even thought I have pretty good basic knowledge but this is  really stopping me from moving forward.

Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think i managed to get a clean installation without too much tweaking. 
Please see the [help page on LiberoSOC](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiberoSOC).

Hope it helps.